# Nested child and subchild route with params

Tags: angular, typescript, parameters, routes, nested-routes

I'm having troubles with nested routes. Here's my situation:

Routing:

```
  RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'workerevaluation', component: MainComponent, children: [
      {
        path: 'details/:code', component: EmployeeDetailComponent, children: [
          { path: '', component: EmployeeTableComponent },
          { path: 'evaldetail/:evalid', component: EmployeeEvaluationDetailComponent }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]),
```

inside EmployeeTableComponent i have a button with a (click) that should redirect me to the 'evaldetail/:evailid' but it throws me this error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'https:/localhost:44352/workerevaluation/details/W002/evaldetail/EVAL123'

It seems to not be recognizing the 'details/:code' subpath.

Any suggestion?

Comment: can you tell your your navigation statememnt?

Comment: this.router.navigate([document.location.href + '/evaldetail', _evaluationId]);

Comment: change it to this.router.navigate(['/evaldetail', _evaluationId]);

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'evaldetail/EVAL123'
I still need the subpath '/details/:code' in the url

Comment: are you ever able to reach employee detail component?

Answer (score 0):

With this route config.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'workerevaluation', component: MainComponent, children: [
      {
        path: 'details/:code', component: EmployeeDetailComponent, children: [
          { path: '', component: EmployeeTableComponent },
          { path: 'evaldetail/:evalid', component: EmployeeEvaluationDetailComponent }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]),
```

You should be having router-outlet in these files.

1. app.component.html
2. main.component.html
3. employee-detail.component.html

Working Stackblitz :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymomja

Note in the stackblitz browser append this after url :- /workerevaluation/details/W002/evaldetail/EVAL123

Comment: With this route configuration the problem is not resolved, in addition it remove all components i have in the MainComponent when I try to navigate to 'details:code' exept for the EmployeeTableComponent

Comment: so you need employee details component?

Comment: i changed my solution above, check that out.

Comment: Yes, i'll show you a preview: https://ibb.co/wJPn4CJ
When i click on "Go to evaluation EVALID" it should swap component from EmployeeTableComponent (called in screen as 'evaluation table') to EmployeeEvaluationDetailComponent

Comment: i changed the solution, check that out bro.

Comment: Ok, as my solution it works if i enter the url, but how to navigate there with a button?

Comment: same navigation statement u was using.

Comment: the solution is the same I posted as problem, router.navigate invoked from the button is still not working...

Comment: <button [routerLink]="['evaldetail/EVAL123']">Go To Detail</button> worked for me.

Comment: @Elbotteon check same url which i gave and go in url till W002, you will see a button. try clicking it.

Comment: ok this button works, but i don't have 15 rep to approve the answer :(

Comment: no problem, but it solved your issue right? happy to help. you can't vote but you can mark it as answer bro. just click on the tick mark below votes. took me lots of effort to solve this.

Comment: yes the [routelink] in the button worked, router.navigate in the *,ts file was the problem

Comment: FYI: if you want to trigger the (click) and use the router.navigate this is the solution: 
    this.router.navigate(['../evaldetail', _evaluationId], { relativeTo: this.route });

Comment: This should not be the case

Comment: No need of ../ check same stackblitz. I have updated it.